# Idempotent and nilpotent matrices are defined differently. Why?

Tags: matrices

We call $A$ idempotent if $A^2$ is $A$.  But we call A nilpotent if $A^k$ is $0$ for some integer $k$.  Why are not they defined uniformly like both with power 2 or both with power some integer $k$.

Comment: They're general definitions in tings which are defined that way. Idempotent elements are associated with projectors, nilpotent elements have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Idempotent is $A^2=A$ not $A^2=I$.

Comment: Why would you expect different things to be defined in the same way?

Comment: @Ted:  Thanks for the correction.  If $A^2 = I, A$ is called involutary.

Comment: @copper.hat:Can it happen that $A^k=A$ with $k$>2.  What would you call such $A$?  If it is uniform definition, it is easy  to remember.  If you give two different things, the same name, there is confusion.  This is my view, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root *potent* in each term refers to (integer) powers. *Idem* means "same", while *nil* refers to "zero". In this sense, the terms are self-descriptive:

- *Idempotent* means "the second power of $A$ (and hence every higher integer power) is equal to $A$".
- *Nilpotent* means "some power of $A$ is equal to the zero matrix".

As Bernard suggests, definitions are made for convenience of use. Both of the preceding occur often enough to deserve a special term.

In practice, the condition $A^{2} = A$ is far more important than:

- For some integer $k > 2$,  $A^{k} = A$ and $A^{j} \neq A$ for $2 \leq j < k$.

Though this "$k$-idempotent" condition may well be useful in some parts of mathematics, I can't recall ever seeing it "in the wild". By contrast, idempotent operators model projections (as Bernard notes), or operations (like pressing the call button of an elevator) that "have no additional effect when repeated".

Incidentally, the eigenvalues of an idempotent matrix are all $0$ or $1$ (and the domain decomposes as a direct sum of eigenspaces), while the eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix are all $0$ (and a non-zero nilpotent matrix is *never* diagonalizable). By contrast, the eigenvalues of a real "$k$-idempotent" matrix ($k > 3$) are not generally real.

Comment: D,Hwang:  Thanks for telling me a lot of things.  In my world, I would like to remember them as idem2potent and nilkpotent.   That is easy for my brain.